# Variance of Sum of independent random variables. Wald's identities.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

> Let $N: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a random variable, and $S_N = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ for $(X_n)_n$ i.i.d. Wald id1: $E[S_N] = E[X_1]E[N]$, Wald id2: $E[S_N^2] = E[X_1^2]E[N]$.
> Prove that $Var(S_N) = -Var(N)\mathbb{E}[X_1]^2 + 2Cov(S_N, N)\mathbb{E}[X_1] + Var(X_1)\mathbb{E}[N]$. Use Walds first and second identity.

My attempt:
I tried proving the equality from right to left.

$$-Var(N)\mathbb{E}[X_1]^2 + 2Cov(S_N, N)\mathbb{E}[X_1] + Var(X_1)\mathbb{E}[N]= $$  $$ = - (E[N^2] - E[N]^2)E[X_1]^2 - 2(E[S_N \cdot N] - E[S_N]E[N])E[X_1] + (E[X_1^2]-E[X_1]^2)E[N]$$

$$=  -E[N^2]E[X_1]^2 + E[S_N]^2 - 2E[S \cdot N ]E[X_1] + 2E[S_n]E[N]E[X_1] + E[X_1^2]E[N] - E[X_1]^2E[N]$$

$$ = -3E[S_N \cdot N]E[X_1] + 3E[S_N]^2 + E[S_N^2] - E[S_N]E[X_1]$$

Any help?

Comment: Could you state all the assumptions that we can make? E.g. Wald's second identity relies on the assumption that $E(X_1) = 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of IID real-valued random variables with finite variance.
Let $N$ be an independent nonnegative integer-valued random variable with finite variance.

For brevity, let $\mu=\mathbb{E}X_1$ and $\sigma^{2}=\operatorname{Var}X_1$.
First, note that for a fixed (deterministic) positive integer $n$,
$$
\mathbb{E}S_n
=\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\Biggr]
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}X_{i}
=n\mu.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\operatorname{Var}S_n
=\operatorname{Var}\Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\Biggr)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\operatorname{Var}X_i
=n\sigma^{2}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_{n}^{2}]
=\operatorname{Var}S_{n}+\left(\mathbb{E}S_{n}\right)^{2}
=n\sigma^{2}+n^2\mu^{2}.
$$
It follows that
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{E}S_{N}
=\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S_{n}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{N=n\}}\Biggr]
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[S_{n}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{N=n\}}]
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}S_{n}\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
=\mu\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mathbb{P}(N=n)
=\mu\mathbb{E}N,
\end{multline*}
establishing what you call Wald's first identity.
Similarly,
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{E}[S_{N}^{2}]
=\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S_{n}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{N=n\}}\right)^{2}\Biggr]
=\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{1\leq n,m<\infty}S_{n}S_{m}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{N=n\}}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{N=m\}}\Biggr]\\
=\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S_{n}^{2}\boldsymbol{1}_{\{N=n\}}\Biggr]
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n\sigma^{2}+n^2\mu^{2}\right)\mathbb{P}(N=n)\\
=\sigma^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mathbb{P}(N=n)+\mu^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}\mathbb{P}(N=n)
=\sigma^{2}\mathbb{E}N+\mu^{2}\mathbb{E}[N^{2}].
\end{multline*}
**Note that this differs from what you call Wald's second identity:
your version is only true in the case of $\mu=0$.**
Combining the above
two identities, we get
\begin{equation}
\boxed{
\operatorname{Var}(S_{N})
=\sigma^{2}\mathbb{E}[N]+\mu^{2}\operatorname{Var}(N)}\tag{1}\label{eq:result}
\end{equation}
To establish equivalence with the expression for $\operatorname{Var}(S_{N})$ that you provide in the problem statement, note that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[NS_{N}\right]
=\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{n}S_{n}n\boldsymbol{1}_{\{N=n\}}\Biggr]
=\mu\sum_{n}n^{2}\mathbb{P}(N=n)
=\mu\mathbb{E}[N^{2}]
$$
and hence
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(N,S_{N})
=\mathbb{E}\left[NS_{N}\right]-\mathbb{E}N \cdot \mathbb{E}S_{N}
=\mu\mathbb{E}[N^{2}]-\mu\left(\mathbb{E}N\right)^{2}
=\mu\operatorname{Var}N.
$$

Comment: @Phosphene: I edited my answer to reflect your edits.

Comment: @parsiad did you assume that $X_n$ and $N$ are independent ($\forall n$)?

Comment: @Snoop: Yes. I edited to add my assumptions. You can relax the independence. Not sure if OP wanted a relaxed version.

Comment: @Phosphene: I removed the extra brackets you introduced in your edits; please do not reintroduce them if possible. I find it harder to read with the brackets.

Comment: @Parsiad no worries. Is this some sort of convention thought? It is not the first time I see the expectation written like this in similar contexts.

Comment: I suppose it's just personal preference. Some people write operators $T$ acting on elements $x$ as $Tx$ when it's unambiguous. It'd be poor form to write $Tx+y$ if you meant $T(x+y)$, however.